# QT - Is it possible to color half of a cell in a QTableView?

Tags: qt, delegates, qtableview

I imagine if it is possible it would involve either re-implementing the function that actually draws the color into the cell, or creating some sort of delegate.

Anybody have experience with this? Would it even be possible?

Comment: You can either create a custom widget, implement its paint event to render whatever, then add it to a specific model index using QTreeView::setIndexWidget(). This can however be pretty slow depending on how many you are adding to your tree. Alternatively you can check out the QAbstractItemDelegate class or any of its derivatives which can be used to provide custom rendering for cells (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemdelegate.html). As you suspected you implement the paint delegate function and use the supplied model index to render anything you like! (see QTreeView::setItemDelegate()).

Comment: I think you can draw the whole cell as you want in overridden `QAbstractItemDelegate::paint()` function of your custom delegate.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is absolutely possible to draw cells of a `QTableView` in precisely the way you want it. Qt is flexible enough to allow that.

Here's an example how it can be done in PyQt5 via a custom delegate:

```py
import sys
import string
import random
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class Delegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate.__init__(self)

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        painter.save()
        left_rect = QtCore.QRect(option.rect.left(), option.rect.top(),
                                 option.rect.width() / 2, option.rect.height())
        left_brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.red)
        painter.fillRect(left_rect, left_brush)
        right_rect = QtCore.QRect(option.rect.left() + option.rect.width() / 2,
                                  option.rect.top(), option.rect.width() / 2,
                                  option.rect.height())
        right_brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.blue)
        painter.fillRect(right_rect, right_brush)
        painter.restore()
        adjusted_option = option
        adjusted_option.backgroundBrush = QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.NoBrush)
        QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, adjusted_option, index)

class Model(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)
        self.column_names = [ "First",
                              "Second",
                              "Third",
                              "Fourth" ]
        self.text_data = []
        for i in range(0, 10):
            row_data = []
            for j in range(0, len(self.column_names)):
                row_data.append(''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase +
                                        string.digits) for _ in range(6)))
            self.text_data.append(row_data)

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        if parent.isValid():
            return 0
        else:
            return len(self.text_data)

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.column_names)

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None
        if role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return None

        row = index.row()
        if row < 0 or row >= len(self.text_data):
            return None

        column = index.column()
        if column < 0 or column >= len(self.column_names):
            return None

        return self.text_data[row][column]

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return None
        if orientation != QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
            return None
        if section < 0 or section >= len(self.column_names):
            return None
        else:
            return self.column_names[section]

class MainForm(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.model = Model()
        self.delegate = Delegate()
        self.view = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.view.setModel(self.model)
        self.view.setItemDelegate(self.delegate)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MainForm()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Basically, we implement a custom delegate being a subclass of `QStyledItemDelegate` and reimplement the `paint` method to do the following:

1. Draw the background of the left half of the cell in red
2. Draw the background of the right half of the cell in blue
3. Set the background brush for the rest of the painting to "No brush" i.e. prevent further painting of the background
4. Call the base class' painting to draw everything else but the cell's background

Here's the end result:

[image: result]

**Upd.**: here's a version of the same code translated to C++: [Half-cell-delegate](https://github.com/d1vanov/Half-cell-delegate)

Comment: I should have been more specific, I am using QT creator 4.3 based on QT5.8.0

I appreciate your answer and it is accomplishing exactly what I want however I am unfamiliar with the syntax of your code. I am using c++. What is your code written in? I have never seen import or code without semi-colons like this.

Comment: It is Python with Qt 5 bindings, PyQt5. Unfortunately, I am stuck without a computer at my hands for a couple of days so while I can translate this to C++, I'd only be able to do this in 2-3 days. Or you can just follow the explained logic and try to do that yourself.

Comment: @JeffWilliams, I've just added a [link](https://github.com/d1vanov/Half-cell-delegate) to C++ version to the bottom of the answer, check it out.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will attempt to implement this today and let you know how it goes.